# Electric Coded Switch

Tags: switching-regulator

I want to **create** a **lighting system** that uses a **push electric switch** that is coded to a specific bulb in a how. When I push **00000001** it lights **bulb 00000001** and when I push **0000010** it lights **bulb 00000010**. Kindly help!

Comment: You haven't showed your effort ! Are they binary ?

Comment: "*... a specific bulb in a how.*" What is a how?

Comment: Do you mean row? You should try to draw the circuit diagram. First for one light bulb with a switch,  and then add another bulb+switch in parallel.

Comment: This has nothing to do with switching regulators, and should not be tagged such.

Comment: the principle is simple, it is only a signal output coded on the high voltage line, received only by an appliance with the same code.

The filter system has two functions,

1) The signal must not go out past

2) The signal must be brought on the 3 electric phases

The buttons can be positioned anywhere in the circuit, same for lamps or any other user.

Answer (score 6):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffpQzn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. This circuit does everything you asked for in your question. Label your switches as required.*

Comment: It certainly does. +1